# The account for the specified project is read only

Tags: oauth-2.0

Can't upload file to google store with OAuth 2.0. Get answer "The account for the specified project is read only". But my Google APIs service account is have status "Can edit". What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem while I was trying to upload file to google store. 
I followed the sample provided  [here](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage). After some googling I found that I just need to use a Google Cloud Storage Project's service account credentials which is billing enabled.

So I think if your GCS project is billing enabled then while you try to upload you will not get **The account for the specified project is read only** this error.